# Is there a way to determine what the SSL port is for a site from an ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl

I have an ASP.NET application. I want to redirect to the secure port for the site, but the site may not necessarily be using the default of 443. Is there some environment variable or API call I can make to determine the currently configured SSL port for a site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897461/read-iis7-configuration-from-within-web-application). So far, I didn't find a solution. If you had admin rights, you could use any number of Microsoft.Web.Administration, WMI or whatever to do it... but inside the web app I didn't find anything

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know this port number upfront and it can't stored somewhere known (such as your `web.config`) you'd need to be able to query the IIS metabase to get the `SecureBindings` attribute of the site's `IIsWebServer` node.

There are a few ways to accomplish this, such as using the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace, but all of them require Full Trust or elevated permissions.

Comment: True, but it's probably simplest to add the magic number of the port to web.config and expect the admins to configure it correctly.  Then you do a simple redirect.

Comment: Agreed, but it looked like the OP was trying to work this on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost totally ignorant of how ASP.NET works, but in general, there's no guarantee that there will be *an* SSL port.  There could be none, there could be 5... I think you'll have to provide this info to your app through some sort of config file.  My apologies if this is not relevant for ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use this [re-direction technique](http://www.jameskovacs.com/blog/HowToAutoRedirectToASSLsecuredSiteInIIS.aspx)?